# useEffect and Client component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

so i'm a new beginner in React development and i'm blocked because of an error so i'm giving you my code (no error detected in vsc) :

My component NavBar :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from '../page.module.css';

export function NavBar() {
    const [isAll, setIsAll] = useState(true); // Nous sert pour agradir la barre
    const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false); // Nous sert à savoir si la personne à scroll

    useEffect (() => { // Ce bloc nous sert à fixer la barre ouverte ou fermé en fonction de si l'utilisateur à scroll ou pas
        const handleScroll = () => {
            const isTop = window.scrollY < 100; // Condition pour savoir si l'utilisateur est toujours en haut du site
            setIsAll(isTop);
            setIsScrolled(!isTop);
        };
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll); // On écoute

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll); // On enlève l'écoute
        };
    }, []);

    const toggleNavBar = () => {
        setIsAll(!isAll);
    } // On rétrécit tout simplement la barre de navigation

    return (
        <nav className={`navbar ${isAll ? 'open' : ''} ${isScrolled ? 'scrolled' : ''}`}>
            <div className="navbar-toggle" onClick={toggleNavBar}>
                <span>
                    <Image src="../images/Theme.png" alt="Logo"/>
                </span>
                <span>Yvan KERDANET</span>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A propos de moi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

And my page.tsx (no error neither) :

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import { NavBar } from './Components/NavBar';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <NavBar/>
  );
}
```

My console indicate that useEffect needs to be in a client components to work but i don't get how to make it work.

I want to animate it to make it minimize when we scroll on the website but because of this compilation error, i can't try and don't how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific and also include the error that you are seeing?

Comment: You are (apparently?) using server components, and the `useEffect` hook only runs client-side. The documentation is [pretty clear about this](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials). Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149867/how-do-i-make-next-js-13-server-side-components-in-the-app-directory-that-depend.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found the problem, just a 'use client' to add on the beginning of my file to make my component a client component and not a server component, thanks for the ref, here is my code now :

```
'use client'

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Image from 'next/image';

export function NavBar() {
    const [isAll, setIsAll] = useState(true); // Nous sert pour agradir la barre
    const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false); // Nous sert à savoir si la personne à scroll

    useEffect (() => { // Ce bloc nous sert à fixer la barre ouverte ou fermé en fonction de si l'utilisateur à scroll ou pas
        const handleScroll = () => {
            const isTop = window.scrollY < 100; // Condition pour savoir si l'utilisateur est toujours en haut du site
            setIsAll(isTop);
            setIsScrolled(!isTop);
        };
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    const toggleNavBar = () => {
        setIsAll(!isAll);
    } // On rétrécit tout simplement la barre de navigation

    return (
        <nav className={`navbar ${isAll ? 'open' : ''} ${isScrolled ? 'scrolled' : ''}`}>
            <div className="navbar-toggle" onClick={toggleNavBar}>
                <span>
                    <Image src="../app/images/Theme.png" alt="Logo"/>
                </span>
                <span>Yvan ...</span>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A propos de moi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Now i have an error on my image Theme.png but that another things

Thanks to those who help